# How to get literal content value in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater

I have a repeater as shown below. How to get the Report ID in code behind (from the expression inside hiddenContent2) ?

The expression is

```
<%# Eval("ReportID") %>
```

Note: I prefer a method that does **not** use "FindControl".

ASP.NET

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptReports" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div></div>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="repeaterIdentifier" class="repeaterIdentifier">
            <div id="reportTitle" class="reportTitle">
                <%# Eval("Title") +":" %>
            </div>
            <div id ="reportFrequency" class="reportFrequency">
                <%# " Frequency - "+ Eval("Frequeny") %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="reportContent">
            <div class="repeaterLine">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailRecipients" runat="server" class="textEdit" Text='<%# Eval("Recipients")%>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hiddenContent2"> 
             <%# Eval("ReportID") %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptReports.Items)
    {
        foreach(Control c in item.Controls)
        {
            string test1 = c.ID;
            Type t = c.GetType();
        }
        string emails = ((TextBox)item.Controls[1]).Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use *Hidden* field instead of hiding the value using CSS attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptReports.Items)
{
    Label lblReportID= (Label)item.FindControl("lblReportID");
    string ReportID = lblReportID.Text;
}
```

If you are using "div", then try this:

```
 <div id="hiddenContent2" runat="server"> 
        <%# Eval("ReportID") %>
 </div>

 foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptReports.Items)
 {
     System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl hiddenContent2 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)item.FindControl("hiddenContent2");
     string ReportID = hiddenContent2.InnerHtml;
 }
```

Comment: Please read the question. I am not using a label inside the hiddenContent2.

Comment: I think it's better to work with your "data" instead of work with value stored in hidden div. Value stored in html could be changed by user.

Comment: I am accepting it as answer since it may work. However I used HiddenField since that seems to be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ItemIndex property of Repeater. This is the sample:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repTest">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="hDiv">
            <%# Eval("SomeID") %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behinde:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var objects =
        new object[] {
            new {SomeID = 1},
            new {SomeID = 2},
            new {SomeID = 3},
            new {SomeID = 4}
        };

    repTest.DataSource = objects;
    repTest.DataBind();
}

protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = (object[])repTest.DataSource;
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in repTest.Items)
    {
        var obj = data[item.ItemIndex];
        var id = obj.GetType().GetProperty("SomeID").GetValue(obj, null);
    }
}
```

So, two things you need to do.

cast DataSource to your type. (I used object[] just for sample).

cast data[item.ItemIndex] to your type. I just use reflection, 'cause I have anonimus type, so if you have a type, you could cast it.