# Fire OnClick and open a dialog from asp ImageButton

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, imagebutton

working for find a solution to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13707166/1528483) I have found another doubt which I can't find solution, that's why I'm here asking for the knowledge of experts.
I have an image button inside a Repetear like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton class ="approvalDialog" runat="server" OnClick = "test_rr" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("aux_approvalId")%>'/>
```

My problem is that the class approvalDialog is opening a jQuery dialog, and if it is opened, the event is not fired, if I delete class ="approvalDialog", the event is firing.

So my question is: If is possible open the dialog and in the same time fire the event? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is working like this:

```
<td class ="approval-img"><asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("aux_approvalId")%>'  OnClick="getApprovalID_approve" OnClientClick="OpenApprovalDialog()" ToolTip="Approve" ImageUrl="/Images/Approve.png" /></td>
```

My problem, I saw that with the console of firebug, was that the javascript function I was calling wasn't defined, and that was because I hade declared it inside the  $(document).ready(function ()

Answer (score 1):

use the onclientclick = "javascriptfunction();"

if it is not working at the same time take a look at this post
[stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155048/onclientclick-and-onclick-is-not-working-at-the-same-time)

also you could also make a webmethod that the jquery/javascript function could call using an ajax call.

Comment: Hi bugz, I tried onclientclick but is not working, also what I could adjust from the post to my app but not lucky. I have to search more information about the webmethod and test it, but if you know some example please let me know.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: can you post what you tried? also did the onclientclick cause the function to fire, is the function in the same aspx page or in a  seperate js file?

Comment: Sure, here there is: function OpenapprovalDialog(){                $.blockUI({ message: $('#approval-form'), baseZ: 10000 });
$('#approval-form').parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
return false;}; <td class ="approval-img"><asp:ImageButton runat="server"  CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("aux_approvalId")%>'  OnClick="test_rr" onclientclick  = "OpenapprovalDialog()"/></td> I have tried with onclientclick  = "return OpenapprovalDialog()" and other ways, also addind the property UseSubmitBehavior="false". The js file is in the same page.